# JS cannot change class name

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following CSS to create triangles:

```
.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 7.5px 10px 7.5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #58BE23 transparent;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-let: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.triangle-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 7.5px 0 7.5px;
  border-color: #F44242 transparent transparent transparent;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

My HTML is like so:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("p5").className = "triangle-up"
</script>
Here is a triangle<i class="triangle-down" id="p5"></I>
```

I want to replace `triangle-down` with `triangle-up`. It doesn't seem to be working though. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When the code runs, the triangle doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @ChrisG how do you mean?

Comment: Move the `<script>` below the `<i>` and it will work.

Comment: The HTML page is executed in a top-down sequential manner. So the script is executed first but the `<i>` is not ready yet. Move the script below the `<i>`, it will work

Comment: I tired that and it's still not finding it. JS error console: `Cannot set property 'className' of null`.